# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method when starting Fragment with EditText (number) Two way databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I'm trying to bind an `MutableLiveData<Int>` to an `EditText` element. I've already implemented the binding adapter but when I start the Activity I get an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to call observer method`

Thanks for help.

**Code:**

**ViewModel**

`val serverPort = MutableLiveData<Int>(9330)`

**XML**

```
    <data>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="...LoginViewModel" />
    </data>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:text="@={vm.serverPort}" />
```

**Adapter**

```
    object Converter {


    @BindingConversion
    @JvmStatic
    fun intToStr(value: Int?): String? {
        return value.toString()
    }

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:text")
    @JvmStatic
    fun captureIntValue(view: EditText?): Int? {
        var value: Long = 0
        try {
            value = view!!.text.toString().toInt().toLong()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return value.toInt()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must try using string value for set `android:text`

```
 <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:text="@{String.valueOf(vm.serverPort)}" />
```

If you using Data binding : two way conversions.
This are a bit difficult because there is no inverse for a static method and certainly no conversion for arbitrary string formats.

String-to-primitive conversions are very common and can be done with a string concatenation syntax with two-way data binding expressions, but only with the empty string:

```
<EditText android:text="@={`` + vm.serverPort}" .../>
```

I'd also suggest you to refer this [page](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-data-binding-inverse-functions-95aab4b11873) for more information on this.

Comment: I already tried that, but I want to implement Two Way Binding. So when I'll do it like you mentioned, I get an exception that there is no inverse operation for valueOf.

Comment: Hi @kauler please check my updated answer, i'd also request you to refer the link if you have any doubts further, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the solution. I used the string concatenation because my usecase isn't that complex at the momant.